# An example with Angular JS and Handlebars in same page

Tags: html, angularjs, handlebars.js

Can We use angularjs and handlebar.js in the same page.
If so how to use angularjs and handlebar.js in the same
html page.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could.  If the handlebar-generated content will contain Angular directives, you will likely need to use the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service after you insert the generated HTML into the DOM.

See also [AngularJS is too humble to say you’re doing it wrong](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/12/02/angularjs-is-too-humble-to-say-youre-doing-it-wrong/) and
 [adding support to angularjs templates, so one can use handlebars or angular in the client-side](https://github.com/gmarty/handlebars-xgettext/pull/4)